# Expo React Native building apk

Tags: react-native, expo

I have been trying to build my apk today but I always face this problem. After completing the build, i download it to my phone and i cannot open it. However, this was not the case 2-3 days ago. I had no difficulties or errors in Run expo doctor. I was able to download the apk to my device and test my app.

[image]

I am not really sure what to do and any help would be appreciated.

This is what I got after running npx expo doctor:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem. I used Android Studio's logcat feature and when I ran the app on the emulator I found the issue - it was related to admob. At this point, I dont need admob, so I deleted its folder from my project and everything was fine after this.

Answer (score 0):

Running expo doctor usually ends up in flagging what dependency needs to be upgraded if the jump to automatically update it goes into the majors like in your case from 4 to 5.

Maybe try upgrading @expo/config-plugins by using expo upgrade or commands from your preferred package manager.

If that’s impossible due to other packages depending on the specific version, maybe consider adding overrides in your package.json. Here is a [helpful article about that](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/how-to-override-your-dependencys-dependencies/).

In my experience this may not be the only reason for the crash of the app. Try running the app consecutively about 3 or 4 times even if it crashes and I believe Android will prompt you to submit a bug report and maybe show you the call stack it failed at.

Let us know how it goes.